# How to rotate an image button to match the screen orientation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I have a layout with several image and toggle buttons. How can I make them rotate to match the screen orientation? I do not with to rotate the layout, just these elements. Example: The screen is in portrait orientation, the buttons are perfectly vertically aligned. The device is rotated and switches to landscape orientation and so the buttons rotate to adapt to the users point of view. How can that effect be achieved? How can a degree rotation animation be linked not only to the element it affects, but also be orientation sensor sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set "android:gravity to center". 
The following layout will hekp for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cool Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There are other ways to do it.

1. Using relative layout
2. Using 2 layouts : 1 one for portrait and and 1 for landscape.

Example for using two layouts:
XML file for portrait mode (found in the res/layout folder)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Apple"  
        android:text="Apple"
        android:layout_width="300dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" />
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Mango"  
        android:text="Mango"
        android:layout_width="300dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" />
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Banana"  
        android:text="Banana"
        android:layout_width="300dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:padding="20dip" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"  />
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Grapes"  
        android:text="Grapes"
        android:layout_width="300dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"   />
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Kiwi"  
        android:text="Kiwi"
        android:layout_width="300dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

We can see that five Button controls are vertically arranged in a LinearLayout container, one below the other. This vertical arrangement makes a few of the Button controls disappear when the screen is in Landscape mode.

To use the blank space on the right side of the screen in Landscape mode, we need to define another layout file, activity_screen_orientation_app.xml, created in the res/layout-land folder. The layout-land folder has to be created manually inside the res folder. Right-click on the res folder in the Package Explorer window and select the New, Folder option. A dialog box opens, asking for the name for the new folder. Assign the name layout-land to the new folder, and click the Finish button.

XM file for landscape mode (found in the res/layout-land folder)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Apple"  
        android:text="Apple"
        android:layout_width="250dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" />
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Mango"  
        android:text="Mango"
        android:layout_width="250dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Apple" />
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Banana"  
        android:text="Banana"
        android:layout_width="250dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:padding="20dip" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" 
        android:layout_below="@id/Apple" />
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Grapes"  
        android:text="Grapes"
        android:layout_width="250dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"  
        android:layout_below="@id/Apple"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Banana"  />
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/Kiwi"  
        android:text="Kiwi"
        android:layout_width="250dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" 
        android:layout_below="@id/Banana" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

We can also detect the screen orientation via Java code. Let’s modify the activity file ScreenOrientationAppActivity.java to display a toast message when the screen switches between landscape mode and portrait mode.

```
package com.androidunleashed.screenorientationapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScreenOrientationAppActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_orientation_app);
   if(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels>getResources().getDisplayMetrics().
            heightPixels) 
        {  
            Toast.makeText(this,"Screen switched to Landscape mode",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Toast.makeText(this,"Screen switched to Portrait mode",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to make another layout for a landscape. Rotate the screen, but the buttons should rotate according to the sensor. But the layout should remain.

Comment: So he has to use another way i.e using relative layout

Comment: There is no issue with the another layout , it is the standard  as per the android docs, but if you still does not want to create another, then you should use Relative layout.